# Write to intended DB location with odbc::dbWriteTable() function

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

There's a bug-like phenomenon in the `odbc` library that has been a known issue for years with the older, slower `RODBC` library, however the work-around solutions for `RODBC` do not seem to work with `odbc`.

**The problem:**

Very often a person may wish to create a SQL table from a 2-dimensional R object. In this case I'm doing so with SQL Server (i.e. T-SQL). The account used to authenticate, e.g. "`sysadmin-account`", may be different from the owner and creator of the database that will house tables being created but the account has full read/write permissions for the targeted DB.

The `odbc()` call to do so goes like this and runs "successfully"

```
library(odbc)

db01 <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "UserDB_odbc_name")
odbc::dbWriteTable(db01, "UserDB.dbo.my_table", r_data)
```

This connects and creates a table, but **instead of creating the table in the intended location of `UserDB.dbo.my_table`, it gets created in `UserDB.sysadmin-account.dbo.my_table`.**

Technically, `.dbo` is a child of the `UserDB` database. what this is doing is creating a new child object of `UserDB` called `sysadmin-account` with a child `.dbo` of its own, and then creating the table within there.

With `RODBC` and some other libraries/languages we found that a work-around solution was to change the reference to the target table location in the call to "`.dbo.my_table`" or in some cases "`..dbo.my_table`". Also I think running a query to `use UserDB` sometimes used to help with `RODBC`.

None of these solutions seems to any effect with `odbc()`.

**Updates**

- Tried the `DBI` library as a potential substitute to no avail
- Found a work-around of sending the data to a global temp table, then using a SQL statement to copy from the temp table to the intended location

Comment: Oops, didn't realize `RSQLServer` is depreciated, it sounds like `odbc()` is the correct approach.

Comment: I would try using `library(DBI)` for the connection though

Comment: @Mako212 I can try it. Our switch to RStudio's `odbc` library from `RODBC` was due to speed increases. I think `DBI` is also fast, but will need to confirm that too to validate it as a solution if it solves the problem we're having with `odbc`. Thanks!

Comment: You also might need to specify a `database` in `dbConnect`, otherwise it could be connecting you outside of the target database.

Comment: Here's a sample connection string from R studio: `con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQLServer",
                 Server = "mysqlhost",
                 Database = "mydbname",
                 UID = "myuser",
                 PWD = "password",
                 Port = 1433)`

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks, but yea still no luck. I will test out DBI tonight, but I have to prove it works on both the original problem and that it's as fast (because whichever way I go gets adopted by others + the data is large, etc.).